# In the context of boost::asio, what is the metaphor behind the term "strand"?

Tags: boost-asio

As a French native, and a boost::asio user, I have added the 'strand' word to my vocabulary (is a 'toron' in French), here an image of a rope made of three strands, an each one made of multiple others:
[image]
But I do not understand the metaphor used by Christopher Kohlhoff, do you ?

Comment: I don't think the recursive nature of real strands of thread is very meaningful in the context of Boost Asio

Comment: It may not be a metaphor.  There is a task-oriented compositional programming language named Strand which predates both Asio and Cilk++ (which also has a strand concept).  For a definitive answer, you will likely have to ask Kohlhoff directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A strand is a logical, sequential path.

Even if many paths intertwine, the paths are continuous and unbroken, and logically distinct.

This is what makes the metaphor work: even though many strands can be intertwined (on many threads, even), the "logical path of code" is never broken, interrupted or collided with another *strand*

[image]

Actually the picture in the question is pretty descriptive and more typical than this, because indeed you will have a limited number of strands doing - typically - similar work in a single direction (forward in time) and in fair alternation (`io_service` is responsible for scheduling tasks for each strand).

Comment: Thanks sehe, not the best metaphor, but it is not easy to give a name for a variable, like for a child ...

Comment: Nicely said.  I have also had success in explaining it metaphorically as a strand of lights (string lights), with each bulb being a handler.