# Is there an "asynchronous message queue" available under boost::asio?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio, message-queue

Within `boost::asio` framework I would like to have some asynchronous queue; it shall allow pushing of objects onto the queue like for a regular queue, but with some kind of non-blocking "asynchronous pop":

```
// outline of an idea only
....
....
std::shared_ptr<AsyncQueue> myAsyncQueue(new AsyncQueue(io_context);
....
auto x = std::bind(
    &AsyncQueue::async_dec,  // pop
    myAsyncQueue,
    myCallback);
....
....

io_context.post(x);
```

The callback shall be executed from an asio-worker thread once something is in the queue.

I looked around; what I found seems to be exactly what I need:

http://hansewetz.blogspot.com/2014/07/using-queues-with-boostasio-part-i.html

I tried to test it, but get an compiler error:

```
//********** Queue Listener Test *****

#include <queue_listener.h>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

// some constants
constexpr size_t maxmsg1{ 10 };
constexpr size_t tmoSeleepBetweenSendMs1{ 100 };

// queue listener handler for queue 1
size_t nreceived1{ 0 };
template<typename T>
void qhandler1(boost::system::error_code const& ec, T item, boost::asio::simple_queue_listener<T>* asioq, shared_ptr<boost::asio::simple_queue<string>>q1) {
    // print item if error code is OK
    if (ec)BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "received item in qhandler1 (via asio), item: <invalid>, ec: " << ec;
    else {
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "received item in qhandler1 (via asio), item: " << item << ", ec: " << ec;
        if (++nreceived1 != maxmsg1)asioq->async_deq(q1, std::bind(qhandler1<T>, _1, _2, asioq, q1));
    }
}
// queue sender for queue 1
size_t nsent{ 0 };
void senderq1(shared_ptr<boost::asio::simple_queue<string>>q1) {
    for (;nsent < maxmsg1;++nsent) {
        string item{ boost::lexical_cast<string>(nsent) };
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "sending item \"" << item << "\"in separate thread ...";
        q1->enq(item);
        this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(tmoSeleepBetweenSendMs1));
    }
}
// test program
int queuetest() {
    try {
        // underlying queue
        shared_ptr<boost::asio::simple_queue<string>>q1{ new boost::asio::simple_queue<string> };

        // asio io service
        boost::asio::io_service ios;

        // asio queue listeners
        boost::asio::simple_queue_listener<string>qlistener1(ios);
        qlistener1.async_deq(q1, std::bind(qhandler1<string>, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, &qlistener1, q1));

        // run a sender thread, run io service and join sender thread
        std::thread thrq1{ senderq1,q1 };
        ios.run();
        thrq1.join();
    }
    catch (exception const& e) {
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "cought exception: " << e.what();
    }
}
```

queue_listener.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef __QUEUE_LISTENER_H__
#define __QUEUE_LISTENER_H__

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>
#include <cstddef>
#include <thread>

#include <utility>
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

namespace boost {
    namespace asio {

        // a simple thread safe queue used as default queue in boost::asio::queue_listener
        template<typename T, typename Container = std::queue<T>>
        class simple_queue {
        public:
            // typedef for value stored in queue
            // (need this so we can create an item with default ctor)
            using value_type=T;

            // ctors,assign,dtor
            simple_queue() = default;
            simple_queue(simple_queue const&) = delete;
            simple_queue(simple_queue&&) = default;
            simple_queue& operator=(simple_queue const&) = delete;
            simple_queue& operator=(simple_queue&&) = default;
            ~simple_queue() = default;

            // put a message into queue
            void enq(T t) {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex>lock(mtx_);
                q_.push(t);
                cond_.notify_all();
            }
            // dequeue a message (return.first == false if deq() was disabled)
            std::pair<bool, T>deq() {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex>lock(mtx_);
                cond_.wait(lock, [&]() {return !deq_enabled_ || !q_.empty();});

                // if deq is disabled or queue is empty return 
                if (!deq_enabled_ || q_.empty()) {
                    return std::make_pair(false, T{});
                }
                // check if we have a message
                std::pair<bool, T>ret{ std::make_pair(true,q_.front()) };
                q_.pop();
                return ret;
            }
            // cancel deq operations (will also release blocking threads)
            void disable_deq(bool disable) {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex>lock(mtx_);
                deq_enabled_ = !disable;
                cond_.notify_all();
            }
            // check if queue is empty
            bool empty()const {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex>lock(mtx_);
                return q_.empty();
            }
        private:
            mutable std::mutex mtx_;
            mutable std::condition_variable cond_;
            bool deq_enabled_ = true;
            Container q_;
        };


        // forward decl
        class queue_listener_impl;
        template<typename Impl = queue_listener_impl>class basic_queue_listener_service;

        // --- IO Object (used by client) -----------------------------
        template<typename Service, typename Queue>
        class basic_queue_listener :public boost::asio::basic_io_object<Service> {
        public:
            // ctor
            explicit basic_queue_listener(boost::asio::io_service& io_service) :
                boost::asio::basic_io_object<Service>(io_service) {
            }
            // async deq operation
            template <typename Handler>
            void async_deq(std::shared_ptr<Queue>q, Handler handler) {
                // wace this->service.async_deq(this->implementation, q, handler);
                this->get_service().async_deq(this->get_implementation(), q, handler);
            }
        };
        // typedef for using standard service object
        template<typename T>
        using simple_queue_listener=basic_queue_listener<basic_queue_listener_service<>, simple_queue<T>>;

        // --- service class -----------------------------
        // (for one io_service, only one object created)
        template<typename Impl>
        class basic_queue_listener_service :public boost::asio::io_service::service {
        public:
            // required to have id of service
            static boost::asio::io_service::id id;

            // ctor
            explicit basic_queue_listener_service(boost::asio::io_service& io_service) :
                boost::asio::io_service::service(io_service) {
            }
            // dtor
            ~basic_queue_listener_service() {
            }
            // get a typedef  for implementation
            using implementation_type=std::shared_ptr<Impl>;

            // mandatory (construct an implementation object)
            void construct(implementation_type& impl) {

                impl.reset(new Impl(
                    //this->get_io_service()
                    this->get_io_context()
                ));


            }
            // mandatory (destroy an implementation object)
            void destroy(implementation_type& impl) {
                impl.reset();
            }
            // async sync deq operation
            template <typename Handler, typename Queue>
            void async_deq(implementation_type& impl, std::shared_ptr<Queue>q, Handler handler) {
                // this is a non-blocking operation so we are OK calling impl object in this thread
                impl->async_deq(impl, q, handler);
            }
        private:
            // shutdown service (required)
            void shutdown_service() {
            }
        };
        // definition of id of service (required)
        template <typename Impl>
        boost::asio::io_service::id basic_queue_listener_service<Impl>::id;

        // --- implementation -----------------------------
        class queue_listener_impl {
        public:
            // ctor (set up work queue for io_service so we don't bail out when executing run())
            queue_listener_impl(boost::asio::io_service& post_io_service) :
                impl_work_(new boost::asio::io_service::work(impl_io_service_)),
                impl_thread_([&]() {impl_io_service_.run();}),
                post_io_service_(post_io_service) {
            }
            // dtor (clear work queue, stop io service and join thread)
            ~queue_listener_impl() {
                impl_work_.reset(nullptr);
                impl_io_service_.stop();
                if (impl_thread_.joinable())impl_thread_.join();
            }
        public:
            // deque message (post request to thread)
            template<typename Handler, typename Queue>
            void async_deq(std::shared_ptr<queue_listener_impl>impl, std::shared_ptr<Queue>tq, Handler handler) {
                impl_io_service_.post(deq_operation<Handler, Queue>(impl, post_io_service_, tq, handler));
            }
        private:
            // function object calling blocking deq() on queue
            template <typename Handler, typename Queue>
            class deq_operation {
            public:
                // ctor
                deq_operation(std::shared_ptr<queue_listener_impl>impl, boost::asio::io_service& io_service, std::shared_ptr<Queue>tq, Handler handler) :
                    wimpl_(impl), io_service_(io_service), work_(io_service), tq_(tq), handler_(handler) {
                }
                // function calling implementation object - runs in the thread created in ctor
                void operator()() {
                    // make sure implementation object is still valid
                    std::shared_ptr<queue_listener_impl>impl{ wimpl_.lock() };

                    // if valid, go ahead and do blocking call on queue, otherwise post aborted message
                    if (impl) {
                        std::pair<bool, typename Queue::value_type>ret{ tq_->deq() };
                        boost::system::error_code ec = (!ret.first ? boost::asio::error::operation_aborted : boost::system::error_code());
                        this->io_service_.post(boost::asio::detail::bind_handler(handler_, ec, ret.second));
                    }
                    else {
                        // wacethis->io_service_.post(boost::asio::detail::bind_handler(handler_, boost::asio::error::operation_aborted, typename Queue::value_type()));
                    }
                }
            private:
                std::weak_ptr<queue_listener_impl>wimpl_;
                boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
                boost::asio::io_service::work work_;
                std::shared_ptr<Queue>tq_;
                Handler handler_;
            };
            // private data
            boost::asio::io_service impl_io_service_;
            std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work>impl_work_;
            std::thread impl_thread_;
            boost::asio::io_service& post_io_service_;
        };
    }
}

#endif
```

The error is:

> 1>D:\software\libs\boost\boost\asio\detail\bind_handler.hpp(165,1):
>   error C2893:  Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type
>   std::_Binder,boost::asio::simple_queue>>>>
>   *,std::shared_ptr>>>>),const
>   boost::arg<1> &,const boost::arg<2>
>   &,boost::asio::basic_queue_listener,boost::asio::simple_queue>>>>
>   *&,std::shared_ptr>>>>
>   &>::operator ()(_Unbound &&...) const'
>   1>D:\software\libs\boost\boost\asio\detail\bind_handler.hpp(165,1):
>   error C2893:         with
>   1>D:\software\libs\boost\boost\asio\detail\bind_handler.hpp(165,1):
>   error C2893:         [
>   1>D:\software\libs\boost\boost\asio\detail\bind_handler.hpp(165,1):
>   error C2893:             T=std::string,
>   1>D:\software\libs\boost\boost\asio\detail\bind_handler.hpp(165,1):
>   error C2893:             _Ty=std::string
>   1>D:\software\libs\boost\boost\asio\detail\bind_handler.hpp(165,1):
>   error C2893:         ]
>   1>D:\software\libs\boost\boost\asio\detail\bind_handler.hpp(165,1):
>   message :  With the following template arguments:
>   1>D:\software\libs\boost\boost\asio\detail\bind_handler.hpp(165,1):
>   message :  '_Unbound={const Arg1 &, const Arg2 &}' 1>Done building
>   project "asn1test_1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Unfortunately my knowledge of `boost::asio` is not deep enough to find that problem...

Comment: Are you on C++ 11 or later?  This gets much easier with just passing a lambda than std::bind.  I'll reply back later tonight if no one else solves your issue.

Comment: @selbie: yes I'm, but what I put as an example at the beginning was just the idea behind. I have no working implementation. I still have to learn boost::asio and bought a book a few minutes ago since I have no idea, what the hansewetz code proposal is doing.

Comment: It looks that you try re-invent asio ! In other words asio does exactly what you want to do, so you have to learn asio, have a look to [Best documentation for Boost:asio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244453/best-documentation-for-boostasio).

Comment: @Jean: Hmmm...maybe you didn't understand me or I'm on a completely wrong path ;-) In asio I can execute asynchronous requests and pass a completion handler along them. For instance I can call asio::async_connect which doesn't block. When the connection is done, I get notified by the completion handler, which is called also asynchronously. For accessing a message queue, however, asio doesn't provide something like asio::async_pop which is not blocking, but calls a completion handler, when the "pop" operation has been completed. Using a regular queue would block. I hope this makes it clear

Comment: @michael You can view `io_service` as a queue. You "push" messages and any workers that `run()` the service `pop` tasks asynchronously. So `workqueue->push_back(job)` can be re-imagined as `post(io_service, [job] { job.run(); });`

Comment: @michael sehe explains exactly what I was imagining ! Thanks Sehe. Michael, you have also to master the strand object, that is very powerful simplifying how to manage concurrency and sequencing tasks, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28669840/888576) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12794107/888576)