# Do i need boost strand

Tags: c++11, tcp, boost-asio

I modified echo example but I have issues understanding boost strand.
Do I need or not?
I yes please be kind and give code for.
I searched examples but I can not understand (Im just stupid..)
Thank you

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include "mingw.thread.h"
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
class session
  : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
public:
  session(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket)
    : socket_(std::move(socket))
  {
  }
  void start()
  {
    input_buffer_str = "[2J[H[A\r\n*ServerV8*\r\nSCAN_BADGE:\r\n";
    out_msg =input_buffer_str;
    do_write(out_msg.length());
  }
private:
  void do_read()
  {
     //  std::cout << "do_read" <<"" <<std::endl;
    auto self(shared_from_this());
```

//async_read_until for Telnet client

```
    async_read_until(socket_,input_buffer_,'\r',
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            do_write(length);
          }
        else
          {
               // std::cout<<ec <<"Disconection?"<<std::endl;
                input_buffer_str.clear();
                out_msg.clear();
                input_buffer_.consume(length);
                // Some Cleanup
          }
        });
  }
```

// async_write back to  Telnet client based on received
// will be result on SQL Query

```
  void do_write(std::size_t length)
  {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    std::istream(&input_buffer_) >> input_buffer_str;
    input_buffer_.consume(length);
      std::cout << input_buffer_str  <<std::endl;
  if (input_buffer_str == "c") close();
    if (input_buffer_str == "a") out_msg = "test_a\r\n";
     if (input_buffer_str == "t")
        {
            Sleep(30000);
         out_msg = "test_t\r\n";
            }
     if(input_buffer_str.length()>0 && out_msg.length()>0)
     {
          input_buffer_str.clear();
        boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(out_msg, out_msg.length()),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
        {
          if (!ec) do_read();
          else
          {
            out_msg.clear();
            input_buffer_.consume(length);
            // Some Cleanup
          }
          out_msg.clear();
        });
     }else  do_read();
  }
```

// close()  Telnet client will be when user pushes F2 (Handheld scanner)

```
void close()
  {
    std::cout <<"Closing..."<<std::endl;
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    input_buffer_str.clear();
    out_msg.clear();
    socket_.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both);
    Sleep(250);
    socket_.close(ec);
   // delete data_;
        if (ec)
        {
            std::cout<<ec << std::endl;
          // An error occurred.
        }
        std::cout <<"Closed..."<<std::endl;
  }
boost::asio::streambuf input_buffer_;
std::string input_buffer_str;
std::string out_msg ;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_;
  //enum { max_length = 1024 };
  //char data_[max_length];
//std::string ClearScreen= "[2J[H[A"; "\r\n*ServerV8*\r\nSCAN_BADGE:\r\n";
};
```

Copy paste from example

```
class server
{
public:
  server(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, short port)
    : acceptor_(io_context, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port))
  {
    do_accept();
  }
private:
  void do_accept()
  {
    acceptor_.async_accept(
        [this](boost::system::error_code ec, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket))->start();
          }
          do_accept();
        });
  }
boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};
```

added Threads Some queries to sql might take depends on Network

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto thread_count = std::thread::hardware_concurrency(); // for multi core
    boost::thread_group     m_Threads;
    boost::asio::io_context m_io_context;
    server srv(m_io_context, 23);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < thread_count; ++i)
        m_Threads.create_thread( [&](){m_io_context.run();});
    m_Threads.join_all();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Strand is the one of the most useful object of asio, and not the hardest to understand and use. But you need to read, read, and read again before being able to answer yourself. Some links:
[In the context of boost::asio, what is the metaphor behind the term “strand”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669840/in-the-context-of-boostasio-what-is-the-metaphor-behind-the-term-strand).   
Also have a deep look to [My answer to asio documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26753331/888576).  
Last but not least, take the time to learn, asio is so powerfull, will be part of C++ standard.

Comment: Thank you.I tried 1 week for now(examples,documentation etc) I  still don't  get it.I had better luck with IOCP examples witch supposed to more complex.Strand I don't makes me give up on this approach :(.

Comment: Helo, found an example in here: https://github.com/senlinzhan/code-for-blog/tree/master/boost_asio and looks good. Thank you senlinzhan  (if you ever see this)